# How to implement a class that has multuple instances, none of which can be equal

Tags: java, design-patterns

My implementation will consist of a java class representing a source repository. I want my implementation to be such that there will be only one object per source repository. If multiple instantiations are done per source repository, I want a unique object representing that source repository to be returned.

Are there any well known patterns/practices to achieve this?

**Note** : If the need was for only a unique object I would have using the Singleton pattern. In my scenario there can be multiple objects with no two objects representing the same source repository.

Comment: A String doesn't work that way, only [interned strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) are guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @rustyx, Agreed. Have edited the title to reflect the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- save a static map repository=>instance.
- make the constructors private
- write a static method to get a instance with the desired repository as parameter
- get the instance from your map or if not present, create it, put it to the map and return it

Comment: the pattern employed here would be the factory method pattern